# How to create Clustered Column Chart grouped by month and person

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm trying to create a clustered column chart that would show a sum of values, by month for each person with each cluster representing the same month. The data that are in the following format:

[image]

I need to create something like this:

[image]

Each bar is a person with a sum for the specific month. The person is appearing multiple times in the table for each month so we need a sum for each month.

I've managed in power bi to create a chart grouped by person and month, but i need the opposite as explained above:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to unpivot your data first. So there will be one row for each date for a person. Then you can achieve your required output using clustered bar chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a lot of columns. The correct way to handle this would be to unpivot your table to transform your columns into rows. See this small sample table:

[image: Table, prior to unpivoting.]

We want to transform the data so that for each column you get one row with `Personen`, `Date` and `Value`. To do this, you can select the name column (and other columns that you want to not pivot), right click, and select `Unpivot Other Columns`. This will yield the following:

[image: Table, after unpivoting.]

You can edit the column names and data types to get the following table:

[image]

And here is your visual, using `Date` as Axis information, `Personen` as Legend information:

[image: Finished!]

Comment: Thanks, working perfectly. Approved and upvoted your answer. One last question. What if we want to provide new data to report? should we unpivot again? is there a way to dynamic do all this thing when we provide new data?

Comment: So the `Unpivot Other Columns` command should handle new columns just fine, since you select only the columns you want to NOT unpivot.

However, this data structure is not ideal since there is a fairly low upper limit of columns Power Query can handle (16000 I think!).

Are you manually structuring the data in this way? If so, I would change my routines (!) , if not, perhaps the system that outputs the data can output the data in an unpivoted fashion.